# Make wordpress downloaded theme header image responsive

Tags: wordpress

I have downloaded wordpress theme Parallax One. I have given a header image, but its not responsive.
I just put an image over the header image, but the image in the top is responsive and the header image not responsive. I want make both images responsive, now it look like this when re-size the window. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You can add your own css code on wordpress admin to make the header responsive, I think.

Comment: i can't find the header css.And i don't know the code to make responsive image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created a div and  created own responsive   css code on wordpress and given the image in that div.It is responsive now.